# Elasticsearch 2.3.4: enabling function_score_query

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use the `function_score_query` for query time boosting. When I run a query like

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 9,
 ....,
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "_type": {
                "value": "news"
              }
            }
          },
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "1000"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
}
```

I got the error:

> scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are
>   disabled.

After searching I found that in `elasticsearch.yml` config file I needed to add the lines

```
script.search: on
script.engine.groovy.inline.search: on
```

And the function score query started working.

However when I do the same on another machine, the elasticsearch service gives an error after restarting. The error is:

> The Elasticsearch 2.3.4 (elasticsearch-service-x64) service terminated
>   with the following service-specific error: Incorrect function.

What may be the problem? I first thought it may be a java RE version problem, but after I set the java RE the same as on the working machine and restarted the node, I still get the same error.

Comment: The one which you mentioned as it worked, was that the ES version 2.3.4 as well ?

Comment: yes, the same ES version

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your `JAVA_HOME` and the `Java Virtual Machine` property is set properly in the machine where the error pops.

Try having your environment variable as `JAVA_HOME` instead of `%JAVA_HOME%`.

Hope these tickets would help you. [18373](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18373) & [3725](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/3725)